# What are all the places that Maven can cache dependencies and/or class files?

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven projects A and B where B depends on A. A defines a class `Foo`, to which I added a field `x`, increased the version number, and did `mvn install`, then matched the version number in `B/pom.xml`, and did `mvn compile`, to see an error that there was no field `x`.

I deleted `A/target`, `B/target` and `~/.m2/repository/A`, and repeated the procedure, to see the same error message.

Now I am baffled. The error itself might just be a mistake on my part, but I would first like to rule out the possibility that an "old" class file is being cached somewhere. To do this I need a thorough way to delete all class files and jars.

Is there a comprehensive list of all the places that class files can be cached?

Comment: Can you provide a subset of the pom.xml for A and B. Specifically so we can view the version and scope of the dependency of A to B. Also if  this is for a java project, can you verify that the namespace of class A is correct in class B

Comment: This is probably beyond the scope of your question, but in cases where I can't tell where some bit of information comes from, I tend to run the process on linux through `strace -f -s10240` to see all the files it accesses, and check which of them does contain a given piece of information.

Comment: If you change something in Project A you need to do `mvn install` and afterwards you can use this in your Project B with the version `1.0-SNAPSHOT`. Furthermore if those projects a tightly coupled like it looks like it sounds more like having a multi-module build instead of two separated projects.

Comment: "and `~/.m2/repository/A`". Artifacts are stored by groupId, then artifactId; would this have caught A?

Answer (score 0):

I know, I have missed the bus here, but adding this info, in case someone else needs this.

By default, Maven local repository is default to .m2 folder :

```
Unix/Mac OS X – ~/.m2
Windows – C:\Documents and Settings\{user-name}\.m2 or C:\Users\{user-name}\.m2
```

But this is very much configurable, via a settings.xml
Location of settings.xml is usually :

```
{M2_HOME}\conf\setting.xml or {M2_HOME}\setting.xml
```

In the settings.xml, look for the entry:

```
  <!-- The default local repository or 'cache' is set to %HOME%\.m2\repository.
       You can override the default by using the <localRepository> tag below. -->

  <!-- <localRepository>C:\path\to\repository</localRepository> -->


  <!--  Mirrors are defined here.  "<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>" is set to catch any
        additional repositories that appear, and instead use the AEDC Build
        Repository.  -->
```